# Image is shrinking in GridLayout

Tags: java, android

I am making a Tic Tac Toe game. For row and column I am using GridLayout and inside GridLayout I am using an image for making borders and in place of x and 0 I am using two coins. But when I put coin's image in GridLayout it shrinks to top left corner.

layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="368dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:columnCount="3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:rowCount="3"
        tools:background="@drawable/board">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/red" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>`
```

image:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you want to create Tic Tac Toe, you need to add 9 `ImageView`s, not just one.
For each `ImageView` or any other view type that's child of `GridLayout` it's better to specify layout parameters `android:layout_row` and `android:layout_column`, which are zero-based indexes, so you have better control over the position of individual children. Otherwise they will be placed one after another based on `android:orientation` attribute of `GridLayout`.
And last, but not least - your image dimension should be 1/3rd of the board dimension, so try to specify its `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` as concrete number, not `wrap_content`. Which leads me to the total width and height of your board, which can't be divided by 3.

And as an off-topic comment - you are specifying `android:layout_marginStart`, `android:layout_marginEnd` together with `android:layout_marginLeft` and `android:layout_marginRight`, which is unnecessary. It's recommended to use `Start` and `End` version rather than `Left` and `Right` in case you want to support RTL devices for Arabic countries.